# Delete Local File after Sync Aws S3 CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have some data inside my Debian server which I want at upload to the AWS S3 by using CLI. So I am succeeded to uploading the data from my server to S3 using this command

`aws s3 sync /var/lib/recordings/ s3://mybucket/recordings/ --recursive --acl public-read`

Now I want to delete that recordings from my debian server after successfully uploading to S3, How should I do this? I just want to delete the debian server recordings data.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: `rm -rf /var/lib/recordings/`

Comment: Thanks,Can I run this command after running sync command?

Comment: yep, for sure can